# Magento 2 , How to avaid load() in loop?

Tags: magento2, controllers, optimization

I have created the custom module with an inline edit in the grid, all working fine. once I have running **phpsniffer with the EcgM2** standard, I get this warning:

```
Model LSD method load() detected in loop
```

Comment: refer this link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10380

Answer (score 1):

Use collection and filters to get list of models u need.

Sample below:

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory */
protected $collectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
) {
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}

public function yourMethod()
{
    // Use factory to create a new product collection
    $productCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    /** Apply filters here */
    $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    // Don't have to do this
    // $productCollection->load();

    foreach ($productCollection as $product){
         echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
    }  
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/139769)

Comment: @RamaChandranM its short, but still an answer ...

Comment: @RamaChandranM I corrected my answer a little bit

Comment: Thanks @sv3n, Thanks for updated ans Wqojciech. Some detail explain will help other.